# How do I filter out objects that match items in array?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell custom object with tags, i.e. `{Tags = 11,12,13,14,15}`. I am trying to filter out objects that contain one or more of the tags. Thus far, I have tried this expression with no luck.

```
Title               : Example One
Year                : 2022
Id                  : 12345
Tags                : {11, 15}

Title               : Example Two
Year                : 2022
Id                  : 12346
Tags                : {14, 15}

Title               : Example Three
Year                : 2022
Id                  : 12347
Tags                : {12, 13}
```

Code:

```
$Filter = ('11','14','15')
$Filtered_Objects = $Objects | Where-Object { $_.Tags -notin $Filter }
```

When I execute the above code, it returns all objects. What I am trying to filter out are objects Example One and Two, with only object Example Three remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Containment Operators**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) can only compare a scalar (a single value) against a collection, however what you're attempting to do is compare 2 collections which the operators simply can't handle. You can however, enumerate the filtering collection (`$Filter`) inside the `Where-Object` scriptblock and check **if any** of the elements in filter is `-in` the `.Tags` collections, then `return $false` else `$true`. This would result in the object with `ID = 12347` from your example.

```
$objects | Where-Object {
    foreach($i in $Filter) {
        if($i -in $_.Tags) { return $false }
    }
    $true
}
```

Another way to do it, using [`Enumerable.Any` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0) from [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-7.0):

```
$delegate = [Func[int, bool]]{ $args[0] -in $filter }
$objects | Where-Object {
    -not [Linq.Enumerable]::Any([int[]] $_.Tags, $delegate)
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I hadn't even considered using a boolean return value in the expression. It's so obvious now. Thanks so much!